# Convert byte string to double precision

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus

I am using the CAN interface with an Arduino Shield and Python3 on my host. I get the following message via serial interface of Arduino:

```
b'0006.381 RX: [00000004](00) 3F FE D8 55 80 00 00 00 \r\n'
```

The 8 byte data is in double precision 1.9278159141540527.
For conversion I use the following python code:

```
struct.unpack('>d', b'\x3F\xFE\xD8\x55\x80\x00\x00\x00')[0]
```

My problem is, that I don't know how to convert the 8 bytes of the message string. I don't know how to get from this: `3F FE D8 55 80 00 00 00` to this `b'\x3F\xFE\xD8\x55\x80\x00\x00\x00'`

I tried to make list of the 8 bytes data in the message, but than I have a list of strings and don't know how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) from your input string:

```
import struct
s = "3F FE D8 55 80 00 00 00"
ba = bytearray.fromhex(s)
r = struct.unpack('>d', ba)[0]
```

Output:

```
1.9278159141540527
```

Comment: @SebastianSchulz you're welcome. Note that "`bytearray` objects are a mutable counterpart to `bytes` objects" (see linked doc). For this simple case `bytes.fromhex(s)` will work as well.